# Do I need to add the copyright notice of the original contributors in the SaaS service contract of a forked AGPL software?

Tags: licensing, gpl, software-as-a-service

#### Context

- I have modified a lot a software that in under Affero GPL.
- I have contributed back what made sense, as it has a completely different direction.
- I plan to build a SaaS around it and charge money for its use.
- The code is public, with both copyright notices in the LICENSE file: mine and the originals.
- In our terms and conditions we say the product is licensed under Affero GPL.
- A service contract with our customers needs to be put in place.

#### Question

After reading half internet about GPL and the full text of the license five times, I still have questions:

1. Do I need to mention in the service contract that the product is under AGPL license? Or in the terms and conditions is enough?
2. Do I need to mention in the terms and conditions or in the service contract the original Copyright notices of some part of the code?
3. Can I put in my landing page "Copyright 2015 BLABLA"? Or I am forced to add also the copyright of the original contributors?

I'm getting in touch with a lawyer and I will put his answers here, but just in case someone have experience in this matter.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: Yes, you must attribute.

The AGPL (especially v3) is about as unambiguous as it gets. Not only do you need to *fully* attribute the source, it's a near-certainty (especially with v3) that *your* code will come under the AGPL whether you like it or not.

If you really have 'read half the internet', then you should know this. It sounds like you are somehow trying to skirt giving attribution to the original creators. Don't go there. Ask [Linksys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_Software_Foundation,_Inc._v._Cisco_Systems,_Inc.), amongst others, what happens when you violate the GPL.